# InputEvent modifiers key

Tags: java, events

When I try to get (`isAltGraphDown`) if the ALT GR key is pressed when I click a button Java returns always false also if it's pressed.

Instead with `e.getModifiersExText(e.getModifiersEx())` it returns Ctrl+Alt !!!

What's the problem?

and If I wanted to know if a user pressed a right Shift key?

Answer (score 0):

When I was on the jEdit mailing list I saw a lot of these types of issues, usually when using non-US keyboard layouts.  Occasionally other software on the system can also cause trouble, but most often it's a JVM bug.  What keyboard layout are you using?